# Gnosis Safe CLI Gass Allowance

Tags: gnosis-safe

I get a message when I try to confirm a transaction on Safe using CLI. I guess the problem is with the gas allowance but I do not really know how to fix it. Here's the error that I get after confirming a transaction. Any help would be much appreciate guys.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/safe-cli", line 8, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safe_cli/main.py", line 150, in main
safe_cli.loop()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safe_cli/main.py", line 135, in loop
self.prompt_parser.process_command(command)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safe_cli/prompt_parser.py", line 173, in process_command
return args.func(args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safe_cli/prompt_parser.py", line 79, in wrapper
return function(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safe_cli/prompt_parser.py", line 211, in remove_owner
safe_operator.remove_owner(args.address, threshold=args.threshold)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safe_cli/operators/safe_operator.py", line 429, in remove_owner
if self.execute_safe_internal_transaction(transaction["data"]):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safe_cli/operators/safe_operator.py", line 704, in execute_safe_internal_transaction
return self.prepare_and_execute_safe_transaction(self.address, 0, data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safe_cli/operators/safe_operator.py", line 731, in prepare_and_execute_safe_transaction
return self.execute_safe_transaction(safe_tx)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safe_cli/operators/safe_operator.py", line 174, in decorated
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safe_cli/operators/safe_operator.py", line 739, in execute_safe_transaction
tx_hash, tx = safe_tx.execute(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gnosis/safe/safe_tx.py", line 380, in execute
self.tx = self.w3_tx.build_transaction(tx_parameters)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1099, in build_transaction
return build_transaction_for_function(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1711, in build_transaction_for_function
prepared_transaction = fill_transaction_defaults(web3, prepared_transaction)
File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 249, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.**call**
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/_utils/transactions.py", line 114, in fill_transaction_defaults
default_val = default_getter(web3, transaction)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/_utils/transactions.py", line 60, in 
'gas': lambda web3, tx: web3.eth.estimate_gas(tx),
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/eth.py", line 868, in estimate_gas
return self._estimate_gas(transaction, block_identifier)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/module.py", line 57, in caller
result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 198, in request_blocking
return self.formatted_response(response,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 171, in formatted_response
raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'gas required exceeds allowance (550000000)'}